# Execute a command before login in linux

Tags: centos7

- I have installed minimal centos 7.
- I want to execute a jar file before login.
- Is it possible.
- If yes, please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the command in your bash profile.

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Just add w/e you want at the bottom.